# Issue with CK Editor (4.5.11) - blocking some tags

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ckeditor

I'm using CK Editor to allow users to submit html formatted comments.  Saving the comments in a mysql db.  I'm trying to strip some tags like `<script> <img> <video> <iframe>` etc.

On form submit, I'm capturing the comment value like this:

```
var commentval = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();
```

Going through ckeditor documentation, I have updated the config.js file like this:

```
   config.allowedContent = {
    $1: {
        // Use the ability to specify elements as an object.
        elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
        attributes: true,
        styles: true,
        classes: true
    }
};
config.disallowedContent = 'img iframe video script; *[on*]';
```

Can someone let me know what i'm doing wrong?   Thanks in advance for your help.